# How to reduce the size of an Electron app?

Tags: electron, electron-packager

I'm getting started with Electron and I downloaded the getting started example project and it clocks in about 150MB.

What is the barebones for an electron project? Can I delete the node_modules folder? I will eventually need to call a process but that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

Use webpack and only ship the dependencies that the app requires. 
Also, use `copy-webpack-plugin` to copy the files you need which are not bundled via webpack.

Do not ship entire `node_modules` folder.

Sample webpack config -

```
    const path = require('path');
    var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

    module.exports = {
        entry: {
            main: './main.ts',
            renderer: './src/renderer.js',
        },
        devtool: 'inline-source-map',
        output: {
            filename: "[name].js",
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ["es2015", "react"]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.tsx?$/,
                    use: 'ts-loader',
                    exclude: /node_modules/
                }
            ]
        },
        target: "electron-main",
        bail: true,
        node: {
            __dirname: false,
            __filename: false
        },
        plugins: [
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                { from: './index.html' }
            ])
        ]
    };
```

So the above creates a `public` folder which is your final bundled output.